# Mapping multiple textures when converting files from .obj to .usdz

Tags: textures, blender, converters, wavefront, usdz

I want to convert an `.obj` file with multiple materials to an `.usdz` file. When running the command it only applies the last material in line to the whole object. The `.usda` file it creates shows that none of the textures are applied to each Material, but a new Material called "StingrayPBS_01" is added.

How to I assign the maps to each material properly?

This is the command I am running:

```
xcrun usdz_converter Chair.obj Chair.usdz -v -a -l \
 -m /Materials/Metal -color_map /Users/user/Desktop/EamesChairResize/metal_texture.jpg  \
 -m /Materials/Seat -color_map /Users/user/Desktop/EamesChairResize/white_texture.png  \
 -m /Materials/Blackmetal -color_map /Users/user/Desktop/EamesChairResize/black_texture.png \
 -m /Materials/Wood -color_map /Users/user/Desktop/EamesChairResize/wood_texture.jpg
```

This is the `.usda` file after converting:

```
def Scope "Materials"
    {
        def Material "Metal"
        {
        }

        def Material "Seat"
        {
        }

        def Material "Legs"
        {
        }

        def Material "Blackmetal"
        {
        }

        def Material "StingrayPBS_0"
        { ...
}
```

I expect each texture to map the corresponding material but it creates a new material.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the Material path from /Material/Metal to Metal and the same for the remaining materials.